# Google Drive: GoogleJsonResponseException: Internal Error 500 OK

Tags: google-drive-api

Hii I am stuck with the same error.

I am trying to call specific folder from Drive.

```
//retrieving files from Drive rootFolder<br>
Children.List request = service.children().list(root_ID);

//setquery to get file with title:Books <br>
request.setQ("title = 'Books'");

//executed the request to retrieve the file list<br>
ChildList children = request.execute();//occured error executing this line

ERROR:com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 OK
```

Coding language: JAVA
OS: Windows 7
Server: Apache Tomcat 7.0

I request you to provide info on how you were able to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure root_ID is a valid folder id? Does the same request work if you don't specify a search query?

Comment: yes the root_ID is a valid folder id. Yes the request works if I don't specify a search query, in this case it retrieved only four files from the folder (while there were more than 50 file items init).

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the Java API. I had the same problem. If you specify a query, it will fail. If you use the online form to test out the children().list() method, it will work with a query.